# Show that if G has an articulation vertex then it's complement has an isolated vertex

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple, connected graph with $n \ge 5$ vertices, diameter equal to 2 and containing an articulation vertex. Show that it's complement $G'$ has an isolated vertex.

A few definitions on terms:
The diameter of $G$ is equal to $max_{v \in V(G)} \{ ecc(v)\} $ where ecc(v) is the eccentricity of vertex $v$. This is equal to $max_{u \in V(G)} \{ dist(v,u) \} $.
An articulation vertex $v$ is one which, if removed, $G-\{v\}$ has more connected components than $G$.
The complement of $G$ is the graph with $V(G')=V(G),E(G')=\{(u,v):u,v \in V(g) $ and $(u,v) \not\in E(G)\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v \in V(G)$ be the articulation vertex. As $G$ is connected, removing $v$ gives us a number of connected components $H_i$. As the diameter is 2, every vertex of each $H_i$ must have a distance from all vertices of $G$ of no more than 2.
The only way for this to be true is if all vertices of all $H_i$ are connected to $v$, as the only path from $H_i$ to $H_j$ for $i \ne j$ must go through $v$.
Obviously then in $G'$, $v$ is an isolated vertex.